# creating QT gui using a thread in c++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, multithreading

I am trying to create this QT gui using a thread but no luck. Below is my code. Problem is gui never shows up.

```
/*INCLUDES HERE...
....
*/

using namespace std;

struct mainStruct {

 int s_argc;
 char ** s_argv;

};

typedef struct mainStruct mas;

void *guifunc(void * arg);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

 mas m;<br>
 m.s_argc = argc;
 m.s_argv = argv;

 pthread_t threadGUI;

 //start a new thread for gui
 int result = pthread_create(&threadGUI, NULL, guifunc, (void *) &m);

 if (result) {
     printf("Error creating gui thread");
  exit(0);
 }

   return 0; 
}

void *guifunc(void * arg)
{

 mas m = *(mas *)arg;

 QApplication app(m.s_argc,m.s_argv);

 //object instantiation
 guiClass *gui = new guiClass();

 //show gui
 gui->show();

 app.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: I fixed your code formatting, but I noticed that several of your previous questions also had to have code formatting fixed by other posters. Please take a few minutes to learn how StackOverflow's markdown formatting language works: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . That link is also available on the right side of the box that you write your question in.

Comment: Thank you Tyler for editing. I actually put <code>...</code> tags but not sure why it did not show properly. I will check out the mentioned link.

Comment: It didn't show properly because `<code>` tags are not the way code is formatted on StackOverflow, hence the need to read about the markdown language.

Comment: Stack overflow uses markdown, not tags like a lot of other sites. Takes a moment to get used to but it's pretty nice after a bit. For example, code chunks are indicated by indenting them with at least 4 spaces. Read up on the link Tyler gave you and you'll get it down in no time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be two major issues here:

1. The GUI is not appearing because your `main()` function is completing after creating the thread, thus causing the process to exit straight away.
2. The GUI should be created on the main thread.  Most frameworks require the GUI to be created, modified and executed on the main thread.  You spawn threads to do work and send updates to the main thread, not the other way around.

Start with a regular application, based on the Qt sample code.  If you use Qt Creator, it can provide a great deal of help and skeleton code to get you started.  Then once you have a working GUI, you can start looking at adding worker threads if you need them.  But you should do some research on multithreading issues, as there are many pitfalls for the unwary.  Have fun!

Comment: Thats right. Documentation says clearly that you can't create GUI in other thread than main ( http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/threads.html#5 ). Read whole page i linked and all should be clear for you now.